# Disable Windows 10 from asking for Live.com password every reboot?

Tags: windows-10, user-interface

Windows 10 used to boot without asking for a password.  Then, Windows made me enter my "live.com" credentials in order to download one of those live-tile apps.  Now suddenly every time I reboot, I have to renter my live.com credentials in order to get into my own computer!

**How do I disable this** so my computer boots right to desktop?

I tried Accounts --> Sign-in Options --> Never ask for password, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 2 methods you can use to get past this.

## convert your profile back to a local profile

Press `Start` -> `Settings` -> `Accounts`.

From there, you should see an option to switch your account back to a local one. This of course means you cannot download apps from the windows store until you convert back.

## use auto-login feature

Press `Start` -> type `cmd` and run the Command Prompt feature.

From there, type `netplwiz` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Uncheck "Users must enter a password..." at the top and hit apply.

Enter your username and password for your live account and hit <kbd>OK</kbd>.

You will now automatically login in windows when the computer starts, but locking the computer will still requiring you to enter your password to unlock.

Do note that this feature will store your password in plain text in the windows registry, and anyone who knows where to look, can find it. You may want to change your password if this is of any concern to you prior to enabling the auto login.

Comment: If you can't remember `netplwiz`, then `control userpasswords2` does the same thing.